# How do I solve: $x'=x^2-1$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$x'=x^2-1$; $x(0)=1$

This is what I have done so far:

$\frac{dx}{x^2-1}=dx\left(\frac{1}{2(x-1)}-\frac{1}{2(x+1)}\right)=dt$

After integrating both sides:

$\frac{1}{2}\log(x-1)-\frac{1}{2}\log(x+1)=t+c$

I then should apply the initial conditions to find c:

$\frac{1}{2}\log(1-1)-\frac{1}{2}\log(1+1)=0+c$

$c=\frac{1}{2}\log(0)-\frac{1}{2}\log(2)$

This is where I get a bit confused. Isn't $\log(0)=-\infty$? If so, what does c equal in this case?

Comment: $$x' = x^2 - 1 \Longrightarrow x' - 1 = x^2$$

so take $v = x^{1-2} = x^{-1}$ and then you have $\frac{dv}{dt} = -x^{-2}\frac{dx}{dt}$ and now we can move on. So multiply everything by $\frac{dv}{dx}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct, and that's a sign that there is no solution of the form you chose with initial condition $x(0)=1$.

There is however another solution. Note, that when dividing by $x^2-1$, you implicitly assumed that $x\neq\pm 1$. But $x=\pm1$ are indeed solutions! Thus, the general solution to your ODE is:
$$y = \frac{1-e^{2t+2C}}{1+e^{2t+2C}}\ \text{or} \ y=\pm1$$

Comment: Arguably $C\to\infty$ gives $y=-1$ and $C\to-\infty$ gives $y=1$.